# Ordenar columnas alfabeticamente GridView C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

queria hacerles una consulta ya que no he encontrado nada en internet
Necesito cargar una grilla de tramites la cual tiene que estar ordenada alfabeticamente por el nombre de tramite, esta seria la grilla y como pueden ver esta desordenada
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Que codigo o como puedo hacer para ordenarla? Ya que por lo que estuve viendo en internet se puede ordenar haciendo click sobre la columna, pero yo preciso que ya se cargue ordenada.
Alguna idea?
Muchas gracias!

Edit: Perdon, aqui les dejo el fragmento de codigo

```
try
        {
            List<Tramite> tramite = LogicaTramites.CargoTramite();
            if (tramite == null)
            {
                lblError.Visible = true;
                throw new Exception("No hay tramites disponibles");
                grdListaTramite.Visible = false;
            }
            else
            {
                grdListaTramite.DataSource = tramite;
                grdListaTramite.DataBind();
                
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            lblError.Visible = true;
            lblError.Text = ex.Message;
        }
    }
```

Asi es como yo cargo la grilla, ese fragmento de codigo se encuentra en el Page_Load

Comment: Pon el código que tienes actualmente para cargar los datos, editar tu pregunta y pega este codigo

Comment: Por favor agrega el código que tienes para que podamos ayudarte de mejor manera

Comment: Disculpen! ya añadi el codigo, no se si precisan alguna otra parte de el, muchas gracias!

Comment: Intenta ordenar tu lista de tramites antes de asignarlo al datasource con linq: tramite.OrderBy(x => x.Nombre) donde Nombre es la columna con la cual quieres ordenar la lista

Comment: En este caso no puedo usar comandos de SQL en el codigo ya que es un requisito. Alguna otra forma de ordenarlos?..

Comment: No es comando de sql, es linq, está bajo System.Linq;

Comment: Genial! me sirvio @DiegoCórdova muchisimas gracias!

Comment: De nada, buen día!, lo agregaré como respuesta por si a alguien le sirve no tenga que verse los comentarios

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para ordenar listas, se puede hacer uso de linq, haciendo referencia del namespace: `System.Linq`

Y modificando la lista de la siguiente forma:

```
tramite.OrderBy(x => x.Nombre)
```

Donde `Nombre` es la columna con la cual quieres ordenar la lista para posteriormente asignarselo de forma normal al DataSource.

Para más ejemplos de Ordenamiento, se puede consultar el siguiente enlace:
https://linqsamples.com/linq-to-objects/ordering

Answer (score 0):

Quizas te pueda orientar, para ordenar por columnas un DataGridView en Winforms utilizo esta función de extension, de la siguiente forma `_gridView.OrdenablePorColumnas<TypeDelItemDeLaGrilla>(this DataGridView gv, BindingSource bs)`

```
        /// <summary>
        /// Agrega la funcionalidad de ordenar las columnas al clickear los titulos
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="T">Type de los elementos que muestra la grilla</typeparam>
        /// <param name="gv">Control DataGridView</param>
        /// <param name="bs">BindingSource de la grilla</param>
        public static void OrdenablePorColumnas<T>(this DataGridView gv, BindingSource bs)
        {
            //hago que todas las columnas sean ordenables
            for (int i = 0; i < gv.Columns.Count - 1; i++)
                gv.Columns[i].SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.Automatic;

            int _previousIndex = 0;
            bool _sortDirection = false;

            gv.ColumnHeaderMouseClick += (object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e) =>
            {

                var _grilla = (DataGridView)sender;

                if (e.ColumnIndex == _previousIndex)
                    _sortDirection ^= true; // toggle direction

                var column = _grilla.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].DataPropertyName;
                var list = bs.DataSource as List<T>;

                bs.DataSource = _sortDirection ? list.OrderBy(x => x.GetType()?.GetProperty(column)?.GetValue(x)).ToList() :
                                                list.OrderByDescending(x => x.GetType()?.GetProperty(column)?.GetValue(x)).ToList();

                _grilla.Columns[_previousIndex].HeaderCell.SortGlyphDirection = SortOrder.None;

                _grilla.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].HeaderCell.SortGlyphDirection = _sortDirection ? SortOrder.Ascending : SortOrder.Descending;

                _previousIndex = e.ColumnIndex;
            };

        }
```