# Ordenar un archivo TXT y mostrarlo en un datagridview

Tags: c#, txt, ordenamiento

Estoy trabajando con un archivo de Artículos que contiene: Código de producto, nombre de producto y stock.

Tengo que ordenar ese archivo y mostrarlo en un datagridview para después ejecutar un corte de control con otros archivos.
El programa puede agregar, quitar y modificar el archivo desde un datagridview y mostrarlo.

Este es el archivo txt: Artículos.txt

```
A001,Televisión,30
A002,Impresora,40
A006,Auriculares,400
A003,USB type C,2
```

Con este código cree la clase de Artículos

```
public class Articulos
{
    public Articulos(string[] Articulo) { Codigo_Producto = Articulo[0]; Producto = Articulo[1]; Stock_Restante = Articulo[2]; }
    public string Codigo_Producto { get; set; }
    public string Producto { get; set; }
    public string Stock_Restante { get; set; }
}
```

Este código muestra lo que esta en el .txt en un datagridview, llamo este método en el Form1_Load y en los botones para agregar, borrar y modificar.

```
private void MostrarDataArticulos()
{
    if (File.Exists($@"{Application.StartupPath}\Artículos.txt"))
    {
        StreamReader _sr = File.OpenText($@"{Application.StartupPath}\Artículos.txt");
        string _x;
        List<Articulos> _le = new List<Articulos>();
        do
        {
            _x = _sr.ReadLine();
            if (_x != null)
            {
                _le.Add(new Articulos(_x.Split(new Char[] { ',' })));
            }
        }
        while (_x != null);
        _sr.Close();
        dataGridArtículos.DataSource = null; dataGridArtículos.DataSource = _le;
    }
}
```

Tengo que ordenar el archivo txt, no el datagridview

```
private void btnOrdenarArticulos_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string[] lineas = File.ReadAllLines("Artículos.txt");
    var cortar = lineas.Select(linea =>
    {
        string[] partes = linea.Split(',');
        return new { Codigo = partes[0], Producto = partes[1], Stock=partes[2] };
    });
    (Aca tengo que ordenar el archivo txt)
    MostrarDataArticulos();
}
```

Comment: Por qué quieres ordenar el archivo? Eso no es lo correcto, lo que se debe de hacer es guardar todo en una lista y ordenar la lista antes de llenar el datagridview

Comment: Necesito ordenar el archivo para cuando haga el corte de control esté todo ordenado, si tenes alguna sugerencia de como hacer eso sería de ayuda

Comment: Ahora me doy cuenta que necesito hacer exactamente lo que me dijiste tú pero no sé como

Comment: Puedes usar linq, aquí te dejo mi respuesta a una pregunta similar: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/405669/166202